# Did some Scholars equate ḍarūrah with Ikrah?

Tags: fiqh, reference-request, islamic-scholar, madhhab, usool-ul-fiqh

I was reading this statement by a Scholar

That some of them (People of Knowledge) do not differentiate between ikrāh (compulsion) and ḍarūrah (necessity), so they make what is permitted in the case of ḍarūrah to be
permitted in the case of ikrāh.
This is based upon the ḥadīth of Muḥammad b. Maslamah
when he killed Kaʿb Ibn al-Ashraf
and based upon the ḥadīth of al-Ḥajjāj Ibn ʿalat

There was no Specific people named so i was wondering if there was any references for scholars who held this opinion. Thank you very much

Comment: Could you please add the source of this statement?